# Merge NAME query into second query matching ID numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here are two simple queries:

```
SELECT EntityID, EntityName FROM EntityRelations.Entities 
 WHERE EntityID IN (SELECT ModifiedByEntityID FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock)
  JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId
WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN '6/1/12 3:00 AM'
                       AND '8/1/12 2:59 AM')

SELECT EntityName, Note, ModifiedByEntityID, ModifiedDate FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock)
  JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId
 WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN '6/1/12 3:00 AM'
                        AND '8/1/12 2:59 AM'
 ORDER BY ModifiedDate ASC
```

[image]
The first gives a small table of names that I'd LIKE to slip into the second query into the ModifiedByEntityID field, having the names appear instead of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EntityName, Note, X.EntityName , ModifiedByEntityID, ModifiedDate FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock)
  JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EntityID, EntityName FROM EntityRelations.Entities 
         WHERE EntityID IN (SELECT ModifiedByEntityID FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock)
         JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId
         WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN '6/1/12 3:00 AM'
                                AND '8/1/12 2:59 AM'))X ON X.EntityID = ModifiedByEntityID 
 WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN '6/1/12 3:00 AM'
                        AND '8/1/12 2:59 AM'
 ORDER BY ModifiedDate ASC
```

EDIT by JerryB:  I was getting an ambiguous EntityName message, so I adapted it to this, and it's working perfectly, thanks:

```
DECLARE @FROM DATETIME, @TO DATETIME

    SET @FROM = '6/1/12 3:00 AM'
    SET @TO   = '8/1/12 3:00 AM'

SELECT et.EntityName, Note, X.EntityName "CSR", ModifiedDate FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock) 
  JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EntityID, EntityName FROM EntityRelations.Entities  
         WHERE EntityID IN (SELECT ModifiedByEntityID FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock) 
         JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId 
         WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO))X ON X.EntityID = af.ModifiedByEntityID  
 WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO
 ORDER BY ModifiedDate ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `JOIN` the two queries into one:

```
SELECT EntityName, Note, ModifiedByEntityID, e.EntityName, ModifiedDate 
FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock)
JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) 
  ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT EntityID, EntityName 
  FROM EntityRelations.Entities 
  WHERE EntityID IN (SELECT ModifiedByEntityID 
                     FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock)
                     JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) 
                        ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId
                     WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN '6/1/12 3:00 AM' AND '8/1/12 2:59 AM')
) e
  ON ModifiedByEntityID = e.EntityID
WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN '6/1/12 3:00 AM' AND '8/1/12 2:59 AM'
ORDER BY ModifiedDate ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The dumb way to do this is to join your two queries and get your desired fields.

```
select a.EntityName,a.Note,b.EntityID,a.ModifiedDate
from
(
SELECT EntityID, EntityName FROM EntityRelations.Entities 
 WHERE EntityID IN (SELECT ModifiedByEntityID FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock)
  JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId
WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN '6/1/12 3:00 AM'
                       AND '8/1/12 2:59 AM')
) as b
inner join 
(
SELECT EntityName, Note, ModifiedByEntityID, ModifiedDate FROM EntityRelations.AssistanceFlags af WITH (nolock)
  JOIN EntityRelations.Entities et WITH (nolock) ON af.EntityId = et.EntityId
 WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN '6/1/12 3:00 AM'
                        AND '8/1/12 2:59 AM'

) as a 
on b.EntityID = a.ModifiedByEntityID
 ORDER BY a. ModifiedDate ASC
```

Of course, this will be a slow query, but would be helpful if you work on small table.